# In which ways do app developers cover costs of cloud services?

Tags: mobile, cloud

I have a few ideas for mobile applications, some of which could benefit from some cloud functionality.

For example, an application might allow a user to take photographs with their phone which would generate a list of thumbnails, imagine a to-do list which comprises photographs rather than the traditional text entries.
With the help of the cloud, the user could sync the thumbnails on multiple devices, or perhaps give access to the list to another person using a push notification to their phone, allowing them to then download the thumbnails. There may also be a cloud-based database being used.

It's a simple scenario but it raises some questions for me.

Most mobile apps are currently either free (maybe monetised with ads) or have an initial one-off cost, yet ongoing cloud services cost money. If I developed an app that had 1,000,000 users all storing photos in the cloud and they use the app for the next ten years then the cloud costs could be substantial yet income from app sales may be low after the initial influx of users.

So how do other developers manage ongoing cloud costs?

Are most apps that make use of the cloud subscription based?

Can someone who has already done this type of thing share their experience regarding cloud costs and app monetisation?

Comment: The same way  app developers cover costs of pizza.

Comment: @Mitch So how do app developers in the above scenario cover the cost of their pizza? The question may seem dumb to some people, and perhaps it is, but for those who have down-voted I would appreciate an explanation of why and perhaps some advice to improve the question.

Comment: You are asking how to fund an app. Seek venture capital. Question is off-topic for SO.

Comment: I'm actually asking how other developers have funded their apps in similar scenarios, I'm here to learn and hopefully help others in the future. If the question is off-topic for SO then I apologise and I'm sure it will be closed by the powers that be in due course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloud storage is pretty cheap so you could go the Apple way and allow free use up to a certain storage limit and then charge for extra space. Another way is to actually store images offline on a local server and then copy back as required. Since these images are only accessible via your app you can send a message to your online server when it looks like an image is about to be required - pre load from your local server and then delete again after some time period. You may need some extra management code but if you know how many devices are registered and whether they all have a copy of the image then there is no need for the image to be available online.